# CSS codes not working as expected for Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

The site is [here](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/list-of-cards/abyssal-warder-fire). I've spent 3 days making it compatible with IE so I guess its time to ask for help.

Here are the three important major discrepancies between IE and other browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Opera:

- IE8 navigation buttons on the right most does not have a shadow (FIXED)
- IE8, IE9 :active styles are not working; I'm informed that it will not work in IE7.
- IE9 drop shadow for triangle not showing up (FIXED)

Please let me know any changes in css code that will help address these issues. I don't have plans to support IE 6.

Comment: I think that shadows + IE8 should be well known that that won't work.

Comment: Weird...I saved a copy of just the HTML of that page to my localhost, set `<base href="http://bfcards.edicypages.com/list-of-cards/abyssal-warder-fire">` so it would load the images and...the shadows appear. If removes some of the `vertical-align: middle;` on your `.box_abilities p` CSS rule though. o_O

Comment: @Marnix: contrary to misconceptions, IE actually have been offering advance css3 transformations since IE 4+ in the form of proprietary MS filters. However, its just really hard to use as its not consistent between IE versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@UrBestFriend: Changing `position: relative` to `position: absolute` for `.nav_shadow {}` fixes the issue for me in IE8.

To fix `vertical-align: middle` not working on `.box_abilities p {}` for me in IE7, I just added `margin-top: 55px;` to make it position more or less in the centre of the container.

Comment: Thanks for this, got the nav buttons' shadows to work. Now only two issues remains XD